# Is the ScriptCache accessed in a project trigger the same cache as the published add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a Google AppScript project for Google Sheets that fetches data from an API and adds it to the spreadsheet. This is already published on the Google Sheet addon store.

I want to run a trigger as frequently as possible to cache the frequently accessed data.

One way I've found how to run something as often as I want (At least every 5 minutes) is through **Current project's triggers** option in the Google AppScript project page (where you edit the code). I could create a function that hits an endpoint to get the most frequently access data, cache them to the script cache (`CacheService.getScriptCache`) and run it every 5 minutes using a trigger.

So, is the `Script Cache` that my code accesses when run from the current project's triggers, is it the the same as the users of the published addon ?

Because if it's not, then the caching obviously won't benefit the users that has installed the addon from the addon store.

Comment: I'm sure you can easily test this. What's stopping you?

Comment: I could test this, yes, but right now I don't have publishing rights and I have to ask someone else to publish it and wait for Google to approve the new version. So I was hoping someone would already know the answer :)

Comment: I'm not sure about Cache, but with Properties Service, Script Properties are NOT specific to the account that installed the add-on.  So, if one add-on user saved a value to a key in Script Properties, and then another user saved a different value to the same key in Script Properties, then your add-on users would constantly be overwriting each other's values.  I'm assuming that this is the same way with Script Cache.  You can publish a development version of your add-on as unlisted, and test the unlisted version.